# Unhandled exception - how to solve it, c++

Tags: c++, pointers, error-handling, constants

I am having troubles with this program.
Compiler gives me, after successfull program compilation this:
Unhandled exception in the "0x0f6bd540 (msvcr100d.dll)" в "progBUS.exe"
What is wrong whith the program, because everything seems to work well, but in the end, after pressing "Enter" to exit console, mistake - Unhandled exception is given. How to fix it?
Thanks a lot!

```
# include <iostream>
# include <cstring>

using namespace std;

template < class T>
void switcher(T &a, T &b){
    T c=a;
    a=b;
    b=c;
}

char* f(char* word){
    static char* ss("u");
    static int iter(0);

    cout<<"word \""<<word<<"\" has been thrown\n";
    if ( strcmp(word,ss)!=0 && strcmp(word,"")!=0) {ss=word; iter=0;} //if another word has been thrown
    cout<<"ss="<<ss<<"  iter="<<iter<<endl;
    static char ret[15];//return word value
    memset(ret, '\0', 14);//clean up ret value

    int len = strlen(ss);
    int j=0;
    if (iter == len-1) return nullptr;//we have reached the end of word

    for (int i=iter;i<len;i++){
        //cout<<"*(ss+i)="<<*(ss+i)<<endl;
        if (*(ss+i)!=' ') ret[j]=*(ss+i);
        else { iter=i+1; return ret;}
        //cout<<*(ss+i);
        j++;
        if(i==len-1) {iter=i+1; return ret;}
    }
    return nullptr;
}

int main(){
    int a=1,b=2;

    cout<<f("fr rewfer ewr")<<endl;
    cout<<f("fr rewfer ewr")<<endl;
    cout<<f("43 34")<<endl;
    cout<<f("")<<endl;
    cout<<f("")<<endl;
    cout<<f("fr rewfer ewr")<<endl;
    //char ss[]("fr rewfer ewr");
    //size_t len = (sizeof ss)/(sizeof ss[0]);
//  cout<<"len="<<len<<endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, you started debugging and stopped to make this question?

Comment: `char* ss("u")` this should be `const char*`

Comment: And also `char* word` should be `const char *` too. Seems like you're trying to write in read-only memory.

Comment: You don't fight errors, you find, understand and fix them.

Comment: Perhaps your system has a broken PAUSE.EXE

Comment: No, this code will *not* result in an “unhandled exception”.

Comment: If you run this from Visual Studio, you'll probably get some better diagnostics at the end of the run.  It will probably indicate a memory corruption, and you can learn about heap debugging a bit to find them.

Comment: Out of interest, why have you opted to re-implement `std::swap()` and not to use `std::string`?

Comment: Your `memset` is too small and you never check whether `f` returns `nullptr`.

Answer (score 3):

You need some discipline. You want to use:

```
f("fr rewfer ewr");
```

Literal string could be in read-only memory. You need to promises you don't change it:

```
char*f(const char* word) ;
```

And you have `s("U");` and `ss=word;` so you need too: `static const char* ss;`
But being `ss` `static` you need to be sure that the content of `ss` keep valid between calls. Make a copy of word?
Now, you have `ret[15]` and make 0 only 14. Why not 15? And you not control that you potentially can write more than 14 char in it. F can return `nullptr`, but in your main you don't test for `nullptr`.
Some of your problems could disappear if you use `std::string` and other C++ standard library facilities.

Comment: You are right! Thank you, we can not output nullptr on screen)

Comment: @VasiliyPetechkin: you CAN output a nullptr. You CANNOT output what it POINTS TO. Don't confuse the two things, since it is the source of all memory management headache

Answer (score 0):

All problem was in

```
cout<<f("")<<endl;
```

when f retirned nullptr